# Then $(U^⊥)^⊥ = U$ and if $k$ is not a field, this is only $\supseteq$.

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a symmetric $k$-algebra with a symmetrising form $s : A → k$. For any $k$-subspace $U$ of $A$ we consider the space $U^⊥$ = {$a ∈ A | s(aU) = 0$}. Then $(U^⊥)^⊥ = U$ and if $k$ is not a field, this is only $\supseteq$.

My question is why this is not equality. I seem to have "proved" it using standard set theoretic argument: suppose $a \in (U^⊥)^⊥$, then $s(au) = 0$ for all $u\in U^⊥$. Since $s(au) = s(ua) = 0$, $a \in U$.

Comment: It might be a good idea to supply your "proof", if feasible.

Comment: i've added my "proof". it doesn't depend on k...  thx!